# Cannot modify header information

Tags: caching, laravel, browser, header, output

I have this piece of code that I would use to refresh the browser cache.

```
<html lang="en">
    <?php header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); ?>
    <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="//goak.it/unnamed.ico" type="image/ico" />
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">-->
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="">
```

The problem is that it gives me this error:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/weuxfyre/app/models/User.php:1) (View: /home/weuxfyre/app/views/header.blade.php) (View: /home/weuxfyre/app/views/header.blade.php)
```

By controlling the code but I do not see the present output. Could someone help me? I thank the possible help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move the header code above the opening  tag.

Comment: I tried a while ago and I noticed that the same error occurs . I tried with another document that does not use the < ! Doctype html > and it works. The cause could be the < ! Doctype > ?

Comment: Ah, if you're outputting <!DOCTYPE html> somewhere prior to this, that would be the issue. You have to have your header code before it.

Comment: The problem is that the < ! Doctype > is inserted anchese in html page does not exist . How can I change ? I tried to put the header () in the main filter but not any different .

Comment: Keep in mind that even whitespace will prevent you from setting the header info. If the <!Doctype> isn't in your code, but shows up in the browser, it's likely the browser automatically added it (so it's probably not the issue). I would go back and make sure that nothing is delivered to browser before the header code. Check for whitespace, comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
<html lang="en">
<?php header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

You have a starting `<html` tag before your first header call.  This starting HTML tag is output.  ANY starting tag, or character in a template will be output.  You shouldn't set headers in a template, you should set them in your `Route::...` callback, or your controller action.

Comment: So I could use them in BaseController?